# Getting a user input inside a loop in Shell Script

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to get a user input inside a while loop in a shell script.

```
ls| while read p
do
   echo $p

   read key
done
```

I cannot `read` the input from `stdin`(keyboard) because my input is piped through `ls`. 
Can someone help me to get a user input inside the loop?

Comment: Why would you pipe ls to a read command ?

Comment: use `read key </dev/tty`  to read from terminal.

Comment: @PS. it worked. same question is resolved in your link as well. I will delete the question.

Comment: @Fawzan: Please see, [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Inian a very good read. +1 for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read from stdin using `file descriptor 0`. or by just using `/dev/tty` . Where `$$` is pid of your current process.

```
ls| while read p
do
   echo $p
   read key < /proc/$$/fd/0
   # OR read key < /dev/tty
done
```